# What does $ C_{-\infty}$mean

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, soft-question, stochastic-differential-equations

This question refers to the link: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/260854/a-roadmap-to-hairers-theory-for-taming-infinities/260941#260941
In the answer of Abdelmalek Abdesselam the following equation is mentioned.
$$
C_{-\infty}(f,g)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\frac{\overline{\widehat{f}(\xi)}
\widehat{g}(\xi)}{|\xi|^{2}} d^d\xi
$$

My question is what does $C_{-\infty}$ mean, specifically the ${-\infty}$ part. Few words and explanation of the equation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is explained in the previous sentence as being a kind of covariance.

Comment: @Ian why did it use minus infinity, I see that it refers to covariance?

Comment: Because it is intended to be an extreme limit of the $C_r$ for $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ defined later.

Comment: @Ian Yes, you are correct, I missed it. I can delete this question now or if you write it as an answer I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C_{-\infty}$ in that answer is a kind of covariance between $f$ and $g$. The subscript $-\infty$ is used because $C_{-\infty}$ is meant to be understood as a kind of limit of $C_r$, defined for $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ later in the answer, as $r \to -\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

It may vary, but typically $C_0$ is the set of all continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$, $C_1$ the set of all functions with continuous first derivative, $C_2$ the set of all functions with continuous second derivative, and so forth, with $C_\infty$ being the set of all functions where all derivatives are continuous. I would assume, then, that $C_{-\infty}$ is the set of all functions which are infinitely integrable, i.e. the functions that you can keep integrating over and over again without worrying about pathological behaviour.

Comment: It seems like a scalar quantity rather than a function?

Comment: Did you read the question (and the linked answer)?  It says that $C_{-\infty}$ is "covariance". Your answer does not make much sense given the equation that is in this question. And those function spaces are usually denoted $C^k$, not $C_k$. $C_0$ typically denotes the continuous functions vanishing at infinity.

Comment: Yeah, my fault. I didn't read the question properly.